# when install cocoapods get Error?

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

I try and gem install cocoapods I get an error :

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

what does it mean???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be root to write into `/Library`, so you need to use `sudo`, as [the instructions](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) tell you:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: my friend I try this code and I got this messegae in last line "17 gems installed"

Comment: How do I know I install cocoapods?

Comment: No idea.  Read the documentation I've linked.  I've answered the question you asked.